# Low FPS in Voxel land generation with OpenGL & LibGDX

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, lwjgl, voxel

I'm having some performance issues related to my implementation of voxel land generation.

I've separated the cubes into chunks of 16x16, and am building these chunks as 1 individual model instance to render. The only faces created for each chunk are the ones exposed to air (meaning no neighboring block on that side).

For some reason I'm only getting about 26-32 FPS when looking at all 36 chunks rendered. If I only render 4 chunks, I get over 300 FPS. I'm trying to figure out what optimization I'm missing in order to get a reasonable FPS considering not much is being rendered.

This is my render code for the world.

```
public void render(ModelBatch modelBatch, Player player) {
    modelBatch.begin(player.getCamera());
    for (Chunk chunk : chunks) {
        if (chunk.canSee(player.getCamera())) {
            chunk.render(modelBatch);
        }
    }
    modelBatch.end();
}
```

As for my chunk render function...

```
public void render(ModelBatch modelBatch) {
    modelBatch.render(chunkModelInstance);
}
```

I'm using a ModelBuilder and appending all the needed faces for each block. Then using that to build a Model and instantiating a ModelInstance for rendering. This is being done during world.create() and not while rendering.

```
private void appendBlock(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, Block block) {
    Vector3 chunkLocation = block.getChunkLocation();

    Block topBlock = block.getAdjacentBlock(BlockFace.TOP);
    Block bottomBlock = block.getAdjacentBlock(BlockFace.BOTTOM);
    Block backBlock = block.getAdjacentBlock(BlockFace.BACK);
    Block frontBlock = block.getAdjacentBlock(BlockFace.FRONT);
    Block leftBlock = block.getAdjacentBlock(BlockFace.LEFT);
    Block rightBlock = block.getAdjacentBlock(BlockFace.RIGHT);

    if (frontBlock == null) {
        Material material = AssetWrapper.getInstance().getMaterial(block.getBlockMaterial().getFront());
        modelBuilder.part("front", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, RENDER_ATTRIBUTES, material)
                .rect(chunkLocation.x + 0.5f,chunkLocation.y - 0.5f,chunkLocation.z - 0.5f,
                        chunkLocation.x - 0.5f,chunkLocation.y - 0.5f,chunkLocation.z - 0.5f,
                        chunkLocation.x - 0.5f,chunkLocation.y + 0.5f,chunkLocation.z - 0.5f,
                        chunkLocation.x + 0.5f,chunkLocation.y + 0.5f,chunkLocation.z - 0.5f,
                        0,0,-1);
    }
    if (backBlock == null) {
        Material material = AssetWrapper.getInstance().getMaterial(block.getBlockMaterial().getBack());
        modelBuilder.part("back", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, RENDER_ATTRIBUTES, material)
                .rect(chunkLocation.x - 0.5f,chunkLocation.y - 0.5f,chunkLocation.z + 0.5f,
                        chunkLocation.x + 0.5f,chunkLocation.y - 0.5f,chunkLocation.z + 0.5f,
                        chunkLocation.x + 0.5f,chunkLocation.y + 0.5f,chunkLocation.z + 0.5f,
                        chunkLocation.x - 0.5f,chunkLocation.y + 0.5f,chunkLocation.z + 0.5f,
                        0,0,1);
    }
    if (bottomBlock == null) {
        Material material = AssetWrapper.getInstance().getMaterial(block.getBlockMaterial().getBottom());
        modelBuilder.part("bottom", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, RENDER_ATTRIBUTES, material)
                .rect(chunkLocation.x - 0.5f,chunkLocation.y - 0.5f,chunkLocation.z + 0.5f,
                        chunkLocation.x - 0.5f,chunkLocation.y - 0.5f,chunkLocation.z - 0.5f,
                        chunkLocation.x + 0.5f,chunkLocation.y - 0.5f,chunkLocation.z - 0.5f,
                        chunkLocation.x + 0.5f,chunkLocation.y - 0.5f,chunkLocation.z + 0.5f,
                        0,-1,0);
    }
    if (topBlock == null) {
        Material material = AssetWrapper.getInstance().getMaterial(block.getBlockMaterial().getTop());
        modelBuilder.part("top", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, RENDER_ATTRIBUTES, material)
                .rect(chunkLocation.x -0.5f,chunkLocation.y + 0.5f,chunkLocation.z -0.5f,
                        chunkLocation.x -0.5f,chunkLocation.y + 0.5f,chunkLocation.z + 0.5f,
                        chunkLocation.x + 0.5f,chunkLocation.y + 0.5f,chunkLocation.z + 0.5f,
                        chunkLocation.x + 0.5f,chunkLocation.y + 0.5f,chunkLocation.z -0.5f,
                        0,1,0);
    }
    if (leftBlock == null) {
        Material material = AssetWrapper.getInstance().getMaterial(block.getBlockMaterial().getLeft());
        modelBuilder.part("left", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, RENDER_ATTRIBUTES, material)
                .rect(chunkLocation.x - 0.5f,chunkLocation.y - 0.5f,chunkLocation.z - 0.5f,
                        chunkLocation.x - 0.5f,chunkLocation.y - 0.5f,chunkLocation.z + 0.5f,
                        chunkLocation.x - 0.5f,chunkLocation.y + 0.5f,chunkLocation.z + 0.5f,
                        chunkLocation.x - 0.5f,chunkLocation.y + 0.5f,chunkLocation.z - 0.5f,
                        -1,0,0);
    }
    if (rightBlock == null) {
        Material material = AssetWrapper.getInstance().getMaterial(block.getBlockMaterial().getRight());
        modelBuilder.part("right", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, RENDER_ATTRIBUTES, material)
                .rect(chunkLocation.x + 0.5f,chunkLocation.y - 0.5f,chunkLocation.z + 0.5f,
                        chunkLocation.x + 0.5f,chunkLocation.y - 0.5f,chunkLocation.z - 0.5f,
                        chunkLocation.x + 0.5f,chunkLocation.y + 0.5f,chunkLocation.z - 0.5f,
                        chunkLocation.x + 0.5f,chunkLocation.y + 0.5f,chunkLocation.z + 0.5f,
                        1,0,0);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think if every face of each block has a different Material instance associated with it, you lose all the benefits of batching, and it is flushing the mesh to the GPU on every single face of every block. You should use shared material instances as much as is possible. I don't use 3D much so I could be wrong. I don't know how sophisticated ModelBatch is as far as grouping like materials and minimizing flushes to the GPU.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe I'm using the same instance for each material type. I have 4 different Materials that are generated on startup, and then stored in a HashMap. The instances are being referenced where needed in the above code snips. I can see why you'd think this, as I didn't put that section of code in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a MeshPart instance per every block face. Each of them potentially has different material bound to it. That results in one render call + texture bind per every single block face.

Proper voxel renderer would aim to have **one render call** per whole chunk or chunklet per render pass. You are potentially doing **several thousands of render calls per chunk**.

Do not create multiple Mesh/MeshPart instances per chunk. Keep just single one and append face vertices to it instead.

You should also ditch Model/Mesh Builder, it's not optimized for your use case.

Take a look at LibGDX voxel demo:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/voxel

You should take this approach. It doesn't have textures though, but if you want to add textures: create a texture atlas with all your block textures and then refer to their (texture regions) uv coordinates in vertex data.

Alternative to texture atlas is a technique called bindless, where you bind all textures at once to multiple units and refer to those (their unit) from vertex data.